# CodeIgniter Linking assets folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have assets folder inside the application folder. 
my baseurl is `localhost/project_ci/`

When I type url `localhost/project_ci/index.php` and 
when I link in views `/assets/css/mainstyles.css` **everything is working fine**.

But when I route to the same page to a different URL such as `localhost/project_ci/index.php/page` the CSS **is not applying**.

If I open console and see... The url is not taking from the root directory instead it is taking from the browser's URL `localhost/project_ci/index.php/page`. I want he url to be taken as `localhost/project_ci/ itself`.

Comment: Should use `base_url()` with css path.

Comment: What is the value of `$config['base_url']` in config? If you leave it blank the framework will try to autodetect it since version 2.0.0. Try to set that value in config: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_ci/'` and I think everything should works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change config base url like this 
`$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";`

Comment: Yes I have added in the config file .. stil the url is referring from browser and not from base url.

Comment: I found it ... actually i din add 'HTTP://' in base_url() in config file.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

you have to set your project path in your config file in the variable called `config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_ci/';`

and after that you can give site_url() or base_url() instead of relative path and your work is done.

**I suggest you to put assets folder out of application folder. it will work fine than.**

Comment: Yes I have added in the config file  .. stil the url is referring from browser and not from base url.

Comment: show me the code how you give css file link in your view file

Comment: I found it ... actually i din add 'HTTP://' in base_url() in config file.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have default function base_url() .So by using this you will get exact url.

Comment: No you are not understanding my question . 


my url is localhost/project_ci/index.php

my link tag is : <link href="assets/css/mainstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

wen i type url : localhost/project_ci/index.php/page    i have the routed the controller correctly ... 

but css is not applying ...

in console it is coming like :  http://192.168.28.129/project_ci/index.php/assets/css/mainstyles.css NOT FOUND

Comment: inside of your html  `<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/yourcssfile.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I found it ... actually i din add 'HTTP://' in base_url() in config file.  Thank you :)